# How can i access cookies directly from WSGI environment

Tags: python, cookies, wsgi

How can i read the values of any cookies from the WSGI environment dictionary. I cant see it anywhere in the WSGI specification, is implemented differently on each server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WSGI environ dictionary in large follows what os.environ looks like in CGI. So, what you do for CGI you do in WSGI for Cookies, with exception that you are looking in per request environ dictionary and not os.environ.

So see something like:

http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/articles/cgi_web_applications_two.shtml#receiving-a-cookie

but instead of os.environ, use environ passed to WSGI application.

Better still, use a micro framework like Flask which encapsulates a lot of this behaviour for you so you do not have to worry about it.